# How do I load sequential images until one doens't exist?

Tags: javascript

I have a number of images in several directories, and I want to be able to load all of the images in a specific directory. E.g.,

```
directory-1
|
---- panel-1.png
| |- panel-2.png
| |- panel-3.png
|
directory-2
|
---- panel-1.png
  |- panel-2.png
```

I have a number of these directories, and there is no pattern to how many `panel` images are in each directory.

I want to load all the images in this directory.

My first approach was to load images until I get a 404 error. However, this doesn't seem to work.

```
const imagesLength = _(Array(15)).map((val, i) => {
    const img = new Image
    let valid = true
    img.onerror = () => {
        console.warn('error loading')
        valid = false
        return false
    }
    img.onload = () => {
        if (_.includes(img, 'naturalHeight')) {
            if (img.naturalHeight + img.naturalWidth === 0) {
                console.log(img.naturalHeight, img.naturalWidth)
                img.onerror()
                valid = false
                return false
            }
        } else if (img.width + img.height === 0) {
            console.log(img.width, img.height)
            img.onerror()
            valid = false
            return false
        }
    }
    img.src = `/images/panel-${i+1}.png`

    return valid // logic being, if valid is false it'll exit out of loop
}).compact().size() // I get 15
```

Not only am I getting the wrong number of 'valid' images, I am also still getting 404 errors. I thought handling errors with `onerror` was supposed to suppress 404 errors.

Other things I've tried:

- try / catch
- _.attempt

Anything else I can ry?

Comment: Do you have some sample images online we can use for a fiddle? Or can you create a fiddle?

Comment: won't suppress 404 ... onerror gets thrown because of 404. The request has to be made to server to know if it exists or not

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a working fiddle for you here: https://jsfiddle.net/wxrwnd08/

It should give you the general idea for an option to achieve what you want. Basically I have just created a recursive callback function that loads an image one at a time, until a 404 is reached.

```
var photos = document.getElementById('photos');

function loadImage(src, cb){
    var img = new Image;

    img.onload = function(){
        photos.appendChild(img); 
        console.log('loaded image:', src);
        cb();
    };

    img.onerror = function(err){
        console.log('error:', err);
        cb(err);
    };

    console.log('attempting to load image:', src);
    img.src = src;
};

function loadSequential(pre, ext, first){
    loadImage(pre + first + ext, function(err){
        if(!err) { loadSequential(pre, ext, first + 1); }
    });  
}

loadSequential('http://www.mycitybynight.co.za/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Tattoo-Mooiness-MyCityByNight-', '.jpg', 35);
```

**note: the photos used were the first sequential list I found**

---

Now as for the 404 errors, I don't think you will be able to avoid this, as you don't know in advance how many images you want to achieve, and it is the browser that handles this before the page. However, if you control the server, you could setup an api that checks for the existence of a particular file before you attempt to download it. If you did this though, then I don't see why you wouldn't just return that actual list of images that are necessary to retrieve and then open the exact list on the client.

This definitely feels like a problem that is better handled server side.

Comment: I agree that it is definitely a server side problem. However, I was merely trying to get a quick prototype out without touching the server. Thanks!